# Displaying markers with polylines on google map

Tags: google-maps

I am trying to add markers to the polylines im drawing from the database values but when i add the markers' code, polylines don't show and markers don't show either.
I am getting coordinates from database for each person's id and displaying polylines on the map. I want to add markers or infowindows but failing to do so.
dynamic.php

```
    <?php
    include "connection.php";
    $i=0;
    $table = mysql_query ("select distinct TeamWorkerId from Map");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($table))
    {
        $i++;

      echo "var flightPath".$i." = new google.maps.Polyline(); var infowindow".$i." = new google.maps.InfoWindow();  function drawLine".$i."() {
        var flightPlanCoordinates".$i." = [";
        $workerid = $row["TeamWorkerId"];
       $ttable= mysql_query("select * from Map where TeamWorkerId='$workerid'");
       while ($trow = mysql_fetch_array($ttable))
       {

         echo "new google.maps.LatLng(".$trow[3]."),";
       }
        echo "];

        flightPath".$i.".setMap(null);

        flightPath".$i." = new google.maps.Polyline({
            path: flightPlanCoordinates".$i.",
            geodesic: true,
            strokeColor: '#FF0000',
            strokeOpacity: 1.0,
            strokeWeight: 2
        });

      google.maps.event.addListener(flightPath".$i.", 'click', function(event) {


            infowindow".$i.".setPosition(event.flightPlanCoordinates".$i.");
            infowindow".$i.".open(map);
        });





        flightPath".$i.".setMap(map);


    }";

Testing.php



    function initialize() 
    {
        var mapOptions = 
        {
            zoom: 3,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.772323,-122.214897),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
        };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);


    }


    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize); </script>
      </head>
      <body >
      <script language="javascript">
        function view ()
        {
            alert ('called');
            drawLine1();
        }
      </script>
      <input type="button" value="show"  onclick='view();'/>
        <div id="map-canvas"></div>
      </body>
    </html>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(e) {

    setInterval(
    function () {
        $.get("dynamic.php",function (data) {
        //  alert (data);
            eval (data);
            });
    }
            ,60000);
    });

    </script>
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (including any HTML and CSS required).

Comment: Stackoverflow does not permit posting the whole code but I have posted it somehow. Kindly recheck and tell me if you can help

Comment: I certainly didn't ask for the whole code. What about **Minimal** is unclear?  Please read the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

```
var map;
```

map seems to be empty. 
I recommend you to do all php code in one part and the js in another, mixing both can be difficult to read and debug

Comment: I am trying to fulfill the requirements. I have to fetch coordinates from database for which I need php. I am accessing this code in a separate html page where map is initialized.

Comment: @hamidkhanlodhi What are the coordinates from the database?

Comment: You can do 2 things, run all php code in a part of the page, and then publishing the results

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($table))
    {
        $flightPaths[]=$row;
    }

then in the js you can do like

    var flightPaths = <?=json_encode($flightPaths);?>;

then you'll have a js var with the contents of the flightpath php variable, you can use js to loop the json var, etc.